# How to retrieve data from three tables

Tags: sql, database, join

I have three table emp admin and login, emp and admin having auto increment each ,I want to retrieve emp_name and date_register from emp table and company_name from admin table and last_login_date from login table and in it there should be no duplicate value in it. I tried every thing cross join, inner join and outer join but did not get required data. Please help. What will be the right query for that? Below is my query which is giving duplicate value:

```
SELECT DISTINCT tb1_admin_detail.comp_name, tb1_employee_personalinfo.emp_fname, 
tb1_employee_personalinfo.date_registered, tb1_employee_login_detail.login_date FROM 
tb1_admin_detail, tb1_employee_personalinfo, tb1_employee_login_detail  WHERE 
tb1_admin_detail.unit_id = tb1_employee_personalinfo.unit_id && tb1_admin_detail.unit_id = tb1_employee_login_detail.unit_id && 
tb1_employee_personalinfo.Active =1 order BY tb1_employee_login_detail.unit_id ASC, 
tb1_employee_login_detail.emp_id asc,  'tb1_employee_login_detail.login_date' desc ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using the '&&' operator which is not T-SQL, use AND, also use INNER JOIN and table aliases to simplify your query. I think the result should look something like this:

```
SELECT adm.comp_name, emp.emp_fname, emp.date_registered, lgn.login_date 
FROM tb1_admin_detail adm
INNER JOIN tb1_employee_personalinfo emp ON adm.unit_id = emp.unit_id
INNER JOIN tb1_employee_login_detail lgn ON adm.unit_id = lgn.unit_id
WHERE emp.Active = 1
ORDER BY lgn.unit_id ASC, lgn.emp_id asc, lgn.login_date desc
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

To get the last login date, that will need either its own pre-select by person, or select max() from login detail on the current employee as a FIELD select.  That's why you are getting multiple rows... every login date will create a new "distinct" entry...  Try

As for your "Order By" clause... Since you are ordering by the admin unit id group first, then employee IDs within that group, the latest login date will never matter as that is the lowest point, and since no duplicate employees, no impact.

Otherwise, you can change the order based on the prequery's LastLogin column descending...

```
SELECT DISTINCT
      ta.comp_name, 
      emp.emp_fname, 
      emp.date_registered, 
      PreQuery.LastLogin
   FROM 
      tb1_admin_detail ta

         join tb1_employee_personalinfo emp
            on ta.unit_id = emp.unit_id
            and emp.Active = 1

            join ( select login.emp_id, 
                          max( login.login_date ) as LastLogin
                      from 
                         tb1_employee_login_detail login
                      group by
                         login.emp_id ) PreQuery
               on emp.emp_id = PreQuery.emp_ID

   order BY 
      ta.unit_id, 
      emp.emp_id
```